# Where is the clipboard located at on android phone?

Tags: android

can someone please help me find the clipboard. I understand when it is save to clipboard I can go and paste my info anywhere. But, is the clipboard saved somewhere with all my copies?

thanks

Comment: Not a programming question on android its related to device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clipboard is a location in memory where the OS saves information that's copied/cut. By default, I believe it only saves the last instance--it's overwritten with each new copy/paste. Do a search for "clipboard" in the Market and you'll find a number of apps for saving clipboard history and reusing the info.